# Avoid Android pushing items off-screen in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-relativelayout

I have two similar problems, both involving an `ImageView` pushing `TextView`(s) around and I can't figure out why. For the list of cards, I'm looking to have the image have its height match its parent while the width scales appropriately, and the text left-aligned just right of the image. For the popup, fit width to parent and scale height with text below.

[image: Current CardLayout output]
[image: Current CardInfoLayout output]

What I'm expecting / looking for:

[image]
[image]

Current `card_layout.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp" >

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:elevation="14dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf ="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="top" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abbreviation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/location"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Current location_info_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/info_image"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_abbreviation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/info_location"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried several solutions from tutorials as well as SO posts with single and nested layouts, but nothing seems to work so far. This is only what I have currently.

1. Solution?
2. Why is the text pushed to the bottom in a LinearLayout instead of appearing directly underneath? Or why is it pushed off the screen in a `RelativeLayout` when using `wrap_content` on the `ImageView` and `layout_toRightOf` on the `TextView`?

Regarding #2, due to the answers on similar questions on SO only posting a solution specific to that problem without any explanation, I can't seem to apply it to my situation. I'm looking for a resource to understand how layouts and views interact (single and when nested) if an explanation would be too long of an answer.

Comment: You should use nested layout and use weight attributes :)

Comment: For the popup, try removing the `layout_weight` on the `ImageView`, and setting its `layout_height` to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Regarding the card, I tried your layout locally and it worked for me. Just to confirm, are the text views definitely visible, using a font colour other than white, and having the text they're supposed to display correctly set programmatically?

Comment: @clownba0t Yes, if I change the layout type / scaling such that all items appear on the same line, then the correct text is visible for each card.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `card_layout.xml` layout, it looks like you simply don't have any vertical alignment for the topmost `TextView`. You have the `android:gravity` parameter there, but it's not the same as `android:layout_gravity`. It only sets how the contents of the view appear *within* the view, it doesn't position the view *itself*. You should add a line like `android:layout_alignTop="@id/image" instead of the gravity.

As for the second one, you've set the card's height to match parent, so there's nothing surprising that it's filling the entire screen. You need to set height of everything (both the layout, and the elements inside) to `wrap_content` and remove the weight attributes, they need to be set to all the views to do anything useful anyway.

One other important thing. I noticed that you didn't specify `android:adjustViewBounds` on your `ImageView`s. You have to set it to `true`, otherwise the views will try to set the scale in regard to the intrinsic drawable size and not scale to preserve the aspect ratio.

Regarding the learning materials, I would read up on how linear and relative layouts work in general first, your problems aren't necessarily connected to nesting things. There are plenty of them on the web by now, I'm sure you can find them yourself. Also don't be afraid to experiment in Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, though I still don't quite understand it. Perhaps a more specific question: Why is it that when I have an ImageView with wrap_content for height&width and scaleType:fitStart nested inside a Layout that at some point has a fixed size, does the ImageView have a massive space to the right of it? I would've expected that it would scale the image to the maximum height, and then have a maximum width of the image + padding, not image + padding + ??... If I set the width explicitly, it works exactly as expected.

Comment: @Asmodean I just noticed that you also didn't specify `android:adjustViewBounds` on your views, I've updated the answer. Hope that helps.